# Invoke function before state updated and pass data to parent component / React.js

Tags: list, reactjs

I'm making a simple react application that a user can create a list and items in it. I'm struggling to find out how to pass data from child to parent component and update state.

I pass input data in child component (AddItem) to parent component(App).

//AddItem.js

```
class AddItem extends Component {

   constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
       items: []
   }
   }

   handleSubmit(e) {
       e.preventDefault(); 

       var newItem = {
       name : this.refs.id.value};

       if(this.refs.id.value ===''){
           alert('Add list')
        } else {
           this.setState({
           items: this.state.items.concat(newItem)
           }, function(){
           this.props.addItem(this.state.items);
        });
        console.log(this.state.items) // this print out Array with data
     }
    }
   render() {
   var divName = 'add' + this.props.idName;
   return (
    <div className='addItemDiv'>
        <h4>Add {this.props.idName}</h4>
        <form ref='form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
        <div id={divName} ref={divName}>
            <label>Name</label><br />
            <input type='text' ref='id' />
        </div>
        <br />
       <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
       <br />
       </form>
    </div>
    );
   }

  }
```

// App.js

```
class App extends Component {

 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
       lists: [], 
       items: {} 
     };
  }

 handleAddList(list) {
      let lists = this.state.lists;
      lists.push(list);
      this.setState({
          lists: lists
      })
 }

handleAddItem(item) {
   console.log(this.state.items) // it print out {}. Data is not passed.
   }
render() {
    return (
     <div className="App">

    <AddList addList={this.handleAddList.bind(this)} />
    <div id="listsDiv" className="List">
    <Lists lists={this.state.lists} items={this.state.items} addItem={this.handleAddItem.bind(this)} />
    </div>
    </div>
    );
    }

    }
```

As I added as comment, `this.state.items` in AddItem.js contains array data but when I passed it to parent component in App.js, `this.state.items` is empty. I doubt that function is not invoked properly in AddItem.js and data is not passed to App.js.

But I cannot figure it out more by myself. It would appreciate your kind help.

Thank you,

Comment: Please format your code properly by adding indentations.

Comment: I edit my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found 2 issues in your code when i ran it.

**Note** : I commented out the Lists component.

```
{/*<div id="listsDiv" className="List">*/}
  {/*<Lists lists={this.state.lists} items={this.state.items} addItem={this.handleAddItem.bind(this)} />*/}
{/*</div>*/}
```

(1) You are not passing the props 'addItem' to Component AddItem.

```
<AddList addList={this.handleAddList.bind(this)} addItem={this.handleAddItem.bind(this)}/>
```

(2) Handle Item is logging a wrong field.

```
  handleAddItem(items) {
    console.log(items);
  }
```

Now, I can see the value being bubbled up to App.

Thanks
Sriram Narasimhan

Comment: Thank you for the comment but I don't understand this part. `<AddList addList={this.handleAddList.bind(this)} addItem={this.handleAddItem.bind(this)}/>` If ran my code, can you see your working code?@Sri  Thanks in advance,

Comment: @aayumi In AddList.js you are using this.props.addItem. If that has to work, you have to pass addItem property from App.js to AddList.js

Answer (score 0):

Function handleAddList override your list and state contain only Lists

```
handleAddList(list) {
      let lists = this.state.lists;
      lists.push(list);
      this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            lists: lists
      }));
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. So what can I to to avoid overriding? I tried to pass `this.state.item` for `addList` function but `this.state.item` is empty.